# Google App Engine connection.session() error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

My App Engine logs show this.

> Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
>
> designed for a production environment, as it will leak
>
> memory, and will not scale past a single process.

Now my nodejs App can't use session. How I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to user authentication, note the following portion of the code from the [AppEngine Node documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users#about_sessions) and [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/blob/master/4-auth/app.js#L39):

```
// In production use the App Engine Memcache instance to store session data,
// otherwise fallback to the default MemoryStore in development.
if (config.get('NODE_ENV') === 'production' && config.get('MEMCACHE_URL')) {
  sessionConfig.store = new MemcachedStore({
    hosts: [config.get('MEMCACHE_URL')]
  });
}
```

The default `MemoryStore` fallback is basically just there for development purposes; you should specify a more permanent/scaleable session storage of your choice for actual usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using PM2 or your server is running multiple threads, with default session storage mechanism. This won't scale pass a single thread solution, which is what you generally use in the development mode.

Hence, in-order to persist the session, you need to store it somewhere. For example, Redis.

```
const EXPRESS         = require('express');
const APP             = EXPRESS();
const EXPRESS_SESSION = require('express-session');
const REDIS_STORE     = require('connect-redis')(EXPRESS_SESSION);

APP.use(EXPRESS_SESSION({
  secret: 'YOUR_SECRET',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  store: new REDIS_STORE({ //storing the session in redis
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379, //redis port, should be 6379 by default
    ttl: 300 //time-to-live, session will be destroyed if no activity in 5 mins
  })
}));
```

<sup>Source of the code: Personal project</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using a **session store** fixed the error.

use this link.
 https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores

In the ***README.md*** under 
***compatible session stores*** there is list of compatible session stores for expressjs.